# Tensorflow, feeding Estimator.fit(batch)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

Could you provide an example of using the high-level API Estimators with placeholders and feeding batches  like for a basic use:

```
for step in xrange(max_steps):
    batch_of_inputs,batch_of_targets= get_batch_from_disk(step)# e.g.batches are stored as list where step is and index of the list
    feed_dict = {x:batch_of_inputs,y:batch_of_targets}
    _, loss_value = sess.run([train_op, loss],
                         feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

How to do the same with Estimator API?
Estimator takes batch_size, steps, input_fuc or feed_fun as an argument of the fit function (see doc https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/contrib.learn/estimators)  but it is not clear for me how to implement a function which will load data as a batch from e.g. disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think whether estimators are really meant to be used with placeholders. They use the concept of `input_fn` which is properly described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/input_fn).

If you realy need to use a placeholder you might use a [`FeedFnHook`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/FeedFnHook):

```
def input_fn():  # empty input_fn, returns features and labels
    return {}, {}

feed_dict = {x:batch_of_inputs,y:batch_of_targets}
def feed_fn():  # feed_fn with hardcoded feed_dict
    return feed_dict

hooks = [tf.train.FeedFnHook(feed_fn=feed_fn)]
estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn, hooks=hooks, steps=1)
```